How to force Mathematica to evaulate LerchPhi[1,0,1] to -1/2
Mathematica fails to  evaluate LerchPhi[1,0,1] (it gives ComplexInfinity). Based on the relation LerchPhi[1,q,1]=Zeta[q], we should have LerchPhi[1,0,1]=-1/2.
My question is how to force Mathematica to evaluate LerchPhi[1,0,1] to -1/2 ?
LerchPhi is the Lerch transcendent function. Thank you,

Limit[LerchPhi[1, s, 1], s -> 0] evaluates to -1/2

Thank you Bob...

This is too long for a comment.
If you evaluate
FunctionExpand[LerchPhi[1, s, 1], s == 0]

the answer you get is PolyLog[s, 1]. The same answer is obtained for
FunctionExpand[LerchPhi[1, s, 1], s == 1]

In order to obtain the $\zeta$-function you need to consider
FunctionExpand[LerchPhi[1, s, 1], s > 1]

Now that we have narrowed this down to proper domain of definition for the parameter s we can quickly inspect if there are any pathological values.
LerchPhi[1, q, 1] // Table[#, {q, 2, 10}] &




and from the above we clearly see that there are no issues.
Finally, having a look at DLMF we can see that indeed $s>1$.
However, to answer your question directly, I think that the best way to do what you want is the following.
customLerch[a_, 0, b_] := -1/2
customLerch[a_, 1, b_] := random
customLerch[a_, x_, b_] := LerchPhi[a, x, b] /; x > 1

which is me trying to tell you, rather than over-writing the built-in functionality create a custom function.

Thank you bmf (+1)

@AliShadhar My pleasure :-)
